# Create an object and then setup init as a method with an assignment giving syntax error

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I had a recent post about this, and I thought it was working but I'm getting a syntax error on my function. I had this code in my JS:

```
function MyModule.init(url) {
  var myXHR = new XMLHttpRequest(),
  seconds = (new Date()).getTime();

  // Load my data
  myXHR.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
    var preXHR = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    data;

    // Some code here
    ....

    preXHR.open('GET', url + '?t=' + seconds); 

    preXHR.send();
  }
});

myXHR.open('GET', url + '?t=' + seconds);

myXHR.send();

...

};
```

With I have this bit in my template:

```
$(function(){
  MyModule.init(' {% url 'catalog.data' %}');
});
```

But as I said the MyModule is throwing a syntax error in the JS file and saying it's undefined in my template. I've then looked around to create MyModule as an object in the JS file with an init method inside like this:

```
var MyModule = {
  init: function(url) {
    ...
  }
}
```

But this also throws an error in my template stating `MyModule` is not defined and in the JS file there is an `Unexpected Identifier` at this line:

```
myXHR.open('GET', url + '?t=' + seconds);
```

And still saying the `MyModule is not defined`. Just need some help on how to implement this as an object and setup init as a method with an assignment. Thank you

Comment: A function name simply can **not** contain a period, it's a syntax error!

Comment: [The basics of your code do work](http://jsfiddle.net/B3zwY/). Is the file in which you've declared `MyModule` loaded _before_ the call to the template? If not it should be.

Comment: @adeneo thanks for pointing that out, this is why I changed it.

Comment: @Andy I have the js file loading before `MyModule` in the template but it's still giving me errors